# Why does my AWT/swing GUI JAR capture stylus event data only in a specific region of the screen on a Windows 8.1 tablet?

Tags: java, swing, touch, windows-8.1, tablet

**QUESTION SUMMARY:** *I generated a .JAR file using Netbeans 7.2.1 for a Java Swing/AWT program developed on Windows 7 (Java version 1.8.0_40), that helps collect user handwriting from the screen. It runs fine on a Windows 7 notebook PC but due to some reason captures handwriting data only on a specific region of the screen on a Windows 8.1 tablet (Java version 1.8.0_45). Could someone kindly tell me why this is happening?*

**DETAILS:** I have a requirement of collecting online handwriting samples (i.e. those acquired from electronic devices like a tablet PC using a pen/stylus and writing surface) for some analysis

Being new to developing programs of this nature, I read up about it on the web and decided to use the Java Swing/AWT toolkits

A person's handwriting is composed of strokes which are in turn composed of points. My objective was to capture:
 - the X- and Y-coordinates of a point on the screen
 - the timestamp of creation of this point
 - the stroke's start-time, end-time and color (color not too important)

To this end I wrote the following program using Netbeans 7.2.1 IDE with Java 1.8.0_40 on a Windows 7 Home Basic OS

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package handwritingsamplerawt;
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class HandwritingSamplerAWT {
    static JFrame frame;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                CreateAndShowGUI(); 
            }
        });
    }

    private static void CreateAndShowGUI() {
        frame = new JFrame("Writing Surface v0.1");
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        frame.pack();
        frame.add(new MyPanel());
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class MyPanel extends JPanel{
    private int x,y;
    static int strokeIndex;
    private long reducedMillis;
    private ArrayList<StrokeInfo> strokes;
    private JButton btnSave;



    public MyPanel() {
        MyPanel.strokeIndex=0;
        this.reducedMillis = 1435800000000L;
        this.strokes = new ArrayList<>();
        this.btnSave = new JButton("SAVE SAMPLE");
        this.btnSave.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                WriteCoordinates();
            }
        });
        this.add(this.btnSave);

        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                x=e.getX();
                y=e.getY();
                SaveCoordinates(x,y,"PRESSED");
                repaint();
            }
        });

        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                x=e.getX();
                y=e.getY();
                SaveCoordinates(x,y,"DRAGGED");
                repaint();
            }
        });

        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                x=e.getX();
                y=e.getY();
                SaveCoordinates(x,y,"RELEASED");
                repaint();
            }
        });
    }

    void SaveCoordinates(int xCoordinate, int yCoordinate, String actionIndicator){
        try {
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            Date currDate = cal.getTime();
            double timeStamp=(double)(currDate.getTime()-reducedMillis);
            PointInfo pointObj = new PointInfo(xCoordinate, yCoordinate, timeStamp);
            switch (actionIndicator) {
                case "PRESSED":
                    StrokeInfo newStroke = new StrokeInfo();
                    newStroke.points.add(pointObj);
                    strokes.add(newStroke);
                    break;
                case "DRAGGED":
                    strokes.get(strokeIndex).points.add(pointObj);
                    break;
                case "RELEASED":
                    strokeIndex+=1;
                    break;
            }
        } catch (Exception ex){
            String errMsg = ex.getMessage();
            System.out.println(errMsg);
        }
    }

    void WriteCoordinates() {
        try {
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss");
            String currTimeString = dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());

            DecimalFormat decFormat = new DecimalFormat("#");
            decFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("D:\\HandwritingCaptures\\HandwritingText\\"+currTimeString+".txt");
            SetStrokeAttributes(strokes);
            ListIterator<PointInfo> pointItr;
            if (strokes.isEmpty()==false) {
                for (int index = 0; index < strokeIndex; index++) {
                    writer.write(strokes.get(index).colour);
                    writer.append('\t');
                    writer.write(decFormat.format( strokes.get(index).startTime));
                    writer.append('\t');
                    writer.write(decFormat.format( strokes.get(index).endTime));
                    writer.append('\n');
                    pointItr = strokes.get(index).points.listIterator();
                    while (pointItr.hasNext()) {
                        PointInfo currPoint = pointItr.next();
                        writer.write(String.valueOf(currPoint.x));
                        writer.append('\t');
                        writer.write(String.valueOf(currPoint.y));
                        writer.append('\t');
                        writer.write(decFormat.format(currPoint.timestamp));
                        writer.append('\n');
                    }
                    writer.append('#');
                    writer.append('\n');
                }
            }
            writer.close();

            SaveScreenshot("D:\\HandwritingCaptures\\Screenshots\\"+currTimeString+".png");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    void SetStrokeAttributes(ArrayList<StrokeInfo> strokeList) {
        double startTime, endTime;
        String colour;
        StrokeInfo tmpStroke;
        ArrayList<PointInfo> points;
        if (strokeList.isEmpty() == false) {
            for (int index = 0; index < strokeList.size(); index++) {
                tmpStroke = strokeList.get(index);
                points = tmpStroke.points;
                tmpStroke.colour = "black";
                tmpStroke.startTime=points.get(0).timestamp;
                tmpStroke.endTime=points.get(points.size()-1).timestamp;
                strokeList.set(index, tmpStroke);
            }
        }
    }

    void SaveScreenshot(String imgFilePath){
        try {
            Rectangle screenRect = new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
            BufferedImage capture = new Robot().createScreenCapture(screenRect);
            ImageIO.write(capture, "png", new File(imgFilePath));
        } catch (IOException | AWTException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(1366,768);
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponents(g);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawLine(x, y, x, y);
    }
}

class PointInfo {
    int x,y;
    double timestamp;

    public PointInfo(int px, int py, double ts) {
        this.x=px;
        this.y=py;
        this.timestamp=ts;
    }
}

class StrokeInfo {
    ArrayList<PointInfo> points;
    double startTime, endTime;
    String colour;
    public StrokeInfo() {
        points= new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

I generated the .jar file using the IDE itself (Project Properties-> Build-> Packaging-> Compress JAR file)

Then copied the .jar file to a HP EliteBook 2730P Notebook PC with JRE 1.7.0.800 and Windows 7 Pro OS (32-bit) where it ran fine collecting handwriting strokes from all areas of the screen

But when I copied the same .jar to a HP Elite x2 1011 G1 tablet with JRE 1.8.0_45 and Windows 8.1 (64-bit) and ran it, I found that strangely it captures stylus inputs ONLY from a specific region of the screen - more specifically towards the upper right. It is completely non-responsive on the other areas

Could someone please help me understand why this is happening? Would have posted couple screenshots here but my low reputation prevents me from doing so.

**ADDITIONAL THOUGHTS:** Would it be better to use .NET or Java FX for developing such a tool for using in a Windows 8.1 environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your panel seems to have a fixed size:

```
return new Dimension(1366,768);
```

Is the resolution of your tablet bigger than that?

Edit:

This should help:

```
private static void CreateAndShowGUI() {
    frame = new JFrame("Writing Surface v0.1");
    // Using the default BorderLayout here.
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    frame.getContentPane().add(new MyPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

However there are still problems with your layout, like the "Save" button jumping around. You should take a look at this tutorial:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html

Comment: Hi @Sleafar I just checked the display resolution of the device and found that it is set to 1920 x 1080 pixels (recommended setting). I changed this setting to 1366 x 768 pixels and re-ran the .jar file but the problem remains albeit in a "reduced" manner - I can still write only towards the upper right but the writable area has now increased. Perhaps I should avoid (overloading) the getPreferredSize( ) method altogether?

Comment: That link was very helpful. Thanks a lot! There is indeed still a lot to read up about layout managers. But for now, I fixed the problem in a slightly different manner. And it was your first reply about the device resolution that set me thinking along the right lines :) Will detail the answer below. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the problem could be related to the hardcoded dimensions became clear on seeing the behavior of the .jar file upon running

The tablet had a higher resolution (1920 x 1080 pixels - found by checking the screen resolution through a right click on the desktop) than the machine I had initially run the program on (1366 x 768 pixels). The dimensions of the writable area towards the upper right corner were infact true to the hardcoded dimensions

Ergo, I modified the overridden method **getPreferredSize()** in the following manner:

```
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        return new Dimension((int)screenSize.getWidth(),(int)screenSize.getHeight());
    }
```

This causes the preferred size components to take on the effective height and width of the screen of the device the .jar is executed on. This is important because *depending on the layout manager used* the treatment of the above method by it *does differ*

The "SAVE SAMPLE" button intermittently still seems to cast its images (non-clickable) on other areas of the screen - this probably might have something to do with the layout manager handling of the UI components. Shall add an edit for that issue too once I find a solution